# Floating Label TextInputLayout insideTextInputEdittext add clear icon right side corner with onclick functionality

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I am trying to add clear icon in edit text box right side corner and able to clear the typed text using text watcher functionality in Android.

At the same I am trying in for Floating label edittext inside. But, I could not able to add the clear icon/button on right side corner of `TextInputEditText`.

Note: I have tried `onDrawableRight` image adding with `onTouchListener` method, some of the situation not work out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#text-fields) with the [pre-packaged](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#text-clearing) `app:endIconMode="clear_text"` attribute.

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_end_icon"
        android:hint="Hint text"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]